# trying to decode data (exporting Abs to MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, delphi, encoding, character-encoding

I have database table:

```
DROP TABLE translation_en_lt;
CREATE TABLE translation_en_lt (
  id INTEGER,
  lt_translation WIDEMEMO BLOBBlockSize 102400 BLOBCompressionAlgorithm ZLIB BLOBCompressionMode 9
);
```

Which was generated using AbsManager (Absolute database manager, Delphi). It seem to be outdated however, and syntax is invalid for current MySQL. Then I have this data entry:

```
INSERT INTO translation_en_lt (lt_translation) values (MimeToBin('cABhAHMAaQBzAGw='));
```

The value for this row, as displayed correctly in the AbsManager, is `pasislinkti`. However, `base64_decode('cABhAHMAaQBzAGw=')` returns `p�a�s�i�s�l` [`base64_encode('pasislinkti')` returns `cGFzaXNsaW5rdGk=`].

How do I get 'pasislinkti' from `MimeToBin('cABhAHMAaQBzAGw=')`? Does it have anything to do with the encoding, zlib (`WIDEMEMO BLOBBlockSize 102400 BLOBCompressionAlgorithm ZLIB BLOBCompressionMode 9`)?

I got comment saying:

> 14:24 VoVo64: guy: looks as if the
>   base64 encoded data is actually UCS-2
>   little endian. decoding
>   cABhAHMAaQBzAGw= to HEX results in 70
>   00 61 00 73 00 69 00 73 00 6c

But I have already tried `iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', base64_decode('cABhAHMAaQBzAGw='))` which resulted in:

```
Notice: iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string in /var/www/ssl/pp.php on line 2 pasis
```

I have also tried: `mb_convert_encoding($u, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8'), mb_convert_encoding($u, 'UCS-2', 'UTF-8')`; neither didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are Base64 strings:

```
cABhAHMAaQBzAGw= -> pasisl
cGFzaXNsaW5rdGk= -> pasislinkti
```

I think your data is being truncated somewhere.  You should look for a MimeToText() function in your database system.  I'd try to dump the data out to CSV and load that in MySQL using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.  You will probably have to rewrite the table schemas by hand.   The BLOBBlockSize.... appears to be for compression of this data. Your new table will take a little more space or you can look into using MySQL's Compress() function.

Something like this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE translation_en_lt (
  id INTEGER, 
  lt_translation MEDIUMTEXT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```